# Using Docker multistage build to create multiple images

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have a project with multiple subprojects and I want to ship a separate docker image for each of them. To increase efficiency, I want to use [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) and am looking for a best practice pattern how this is to be done in the most efficient and intuitive way. So far I have found two possibilities, both with drawbacks:

#### Multiple Dockerfiles and build calls

I can make one Dockerfile for the builder image

```
FROM maven as builder

COPY . /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN mvn -e clean install
```

and separate Dockerfiles for each subproject

```
FROM my_builder as builder

FROM openjdk:jre-slim as proj1

COPY --from=builder /build/proj1.jar /somewhere/
CMD ["java", "-jar","/somewhere/proj1.jar"]
```

This works, but the drawback is, that I have to build my images in multiple steps and the Dockerfiles of the subprojects can not be built by themselves:

```
docker build -t my_builder .
docker build proj1/
docker build proj2/
```

#### Using a docker-compose file

I can remove this problem by using a docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
   builder:
      build:
         context: ./
   proj1:
     build:
       target: proj1
       context: ./proj1
     depends_on:
       - builder
   proj2:
     build:
       target: proj2
       context: ./proj2
     depends_on:
       - builder
```

This has the advantage of being able to run the build with a single command

```
docker-compose build
```

but has the drawback of creating a unneeded and artificial dependency for docker-compose which is not needed in the project.

#### Building the whole project in all subprojects

I could also add the buildstage to all Dockerfiles

```
FROM maven as builder

COPY . /build
WORKDIR /build
RUN mvn -e clean install

FROM openjdk:jre-slim as proj1

COPY --from=builder /build/proj1.jar /somewhere/
CMD ["java", "-jar","/somewhere/proj1.jar"]
```

This would have the advantage that I can build each project's container by itself

```
docker build proj1/
```

On the other hand, it it less efficient and violates the DRY principal (the first part of each Dockerfile is repeated over and over again).

#### Best Practice?

Is there a better way to do this? Preferably even one which would work with a single Dockerfile?

Comment: did you consider to wrap the process with maven, gradle or another build tools?

Comment: @YuriG.I did. A simple bash script would suffice. But it's a dirty hack, similar to the builder pattern before docker introduced multistage builds. I would really like to avoid that and find a clean docker-only solution.

Comment: so, what's the problem? create a simple bash script with simple error handling, post here and the community will give a feedback

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: several projects that shared some common Dockerfile lines, but had a few differences. There's a couple of ways that you can solve this with a single Dockerfile.

First, you can do a fan out method:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base
RUN echo "base" >> /history.txt
CMD cat /history.txt


FROM base as variant0
RUN echo "variant0" >> /history.txt

FROM base as variant1
RUN echo "variant1" >> /history.txt
```

Then during your build you just select which one you want using `--target`:

```sh
docker build --file=fan-out.dockerfile --target=variant0 --tag=fan-out/variant0 ./
```

Alternatively, sometimes your project has the shared steps at the end instead of the beginning. You could do something like this, what I call the fan-in method:

```
ARG variant

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as variant0
RUN echo "variant0" >> /history.txt

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as variant1
RUN echo "variant1" >> /history.txt

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as variant2
RUN echo "variant2" >> /history.txt

FROM $variant as join
# pass, do nothing

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as final
COPY --from=join /history.txt /
RUN echo "final" >> /history.txt
CMD cat /history.txt
```

And build it with a `--build-arg`:

```sh
docker build --file=fan-in.dockerfile --target=final --build-arg="variant=variant1" --tag=fan-in/variant1 ./
```

In either of these methods, you'll probably want to have a makefile or shell script to keep track of the commands for each variation.

I wrote up a [blog post](https://srlm.io/2020/03/24/dockerfile-composition/) with some more details.

Comment: It is a bit of a hack, but a nice hack. If you are running the third stage, the first and second runs also. But the second makes an unused image that has no effect on the output.